# How to set my parachain xcm version

Tags: polkadot, xcm

How do I ensure that the XCM version of two parallel chains is the same, how do I change the XCM version, and how do I view the current XCM version.

Answer (score 7):

The XCM version is located in the XCM pallet, and there are two ways of setting it: either via the pallet's `GenesisConfig` by filling out the `safe_xcm_version` field during runtime construction, or dynamically via the `force_default_xcm_version` extrinsic. As a corollary, the supported XCM version that the XCM pallet supports can easily viewed by querying its `SafeXcmVersion` storage value.

XCM versioning between parachains do not need to be manually handled most of the time if they both use the XCM pallet as their `SubscriptionService` in their XCM configuration, since the XCM pallet handles version negotiation and conversion between the source and destination automatically.